# UIImageView not changing size when updating frame property

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I am using Swift iOS 8.0. I have the following UI setup for a UIViewController, which I have created using the Interface builder in Xcode 6.1.1.

- The main UIView (MainView)
- Within this main UIView I have four sub UIViews layered horizontally running down the screen
- Within each of these UIViews I have other types of views (UIImageViews, UILabels etc)

Now let's take the top sub UIView (I will call it SubView1). It has a UIImageView within it. I want to do two things programmatically (I do not want to use AutoLayout):

1. Change the size of SubView1 based on the size of the MainView
2. Change the UIImageView based on the new size of SubView1.

Currently I have the following code which is attempting to do this (this has not been refactored yet):

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var mainViewWidth = self.view.bounds.width
    var mainViewHeight = self.view.bounds.height

    // calculate new size for subView
    var subViewHeight : CGFloat = mainViewHeight / 4
    var subViewWidth : CGFloat  = mainViewWidth

    var nextXPosn : CGFloat  = 0
    var nextYPosn : CGFloat  = 0

    // change frame size for SubView1
    self.subView1.frame = CGRect(x: nextXPosn, y: nextYPosn, width: subViewWidth, height: subViewHeight)

    var originalSubViewHeight : CGFloat = originalMainViewHeight / 4.0
    var scaleFactor : CGFloat = subViewHeight / originalSubViewHeight

    // calculate new height and width for image
    var newHeight : CGFloat = subImage.bounds.height * scaleFactor
    var newWidth : CGFloat = subImage.bounds.width * scaleFactor

    // change frame size and position for image
    self.subImage.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: newWidth, height: newHeight)

}
```

Please note that I have used arbitrary values for x and y positions. When this code executes neither does the size or the position change for subImage or subView1. Is there something I am not setting to allow for these views to change position and size? Why is nothing changing?

Note: what I just tried was to remove the line that changes the size for subView1

```
self.subView1.frame = CGRect(x: nextXPosn, y: nextYPosn, width: subViewWidth, height:
```

subViewHeight)

and the subImage size and position now changes. It seems as though by moving and changing the size of subView1, it prevents the change of size and position for subImage (it's child view). I am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.subView1.frame = CGRectMake(x: nextXPosn, y: nextYPosn, width: subViewWidth, height: subViewHeight)
```

You were using CGRect, instead of using CGRectMake.

Comment: Thanks Byron. Unfortunately this does not work. What is the difference between CGRect and CGRectMake?

Comment: Damn... II will try recreate your problem when I get a chance. At the moment, CGRect and CGRect make have very little difference. Its more for resilience incase CGRect is evolved later on into it owns class. I just figured it was worth a try as I always use it. It also helps with readability in my opinion :)